# Read stdin triggered by key event without dropping first letter

Tags: multithreading, events, rust, locking, stdin

### Context

I am working on a pomodoro command line app written in rust, most of it worked well but now I want to edit the text of a pomodoro item in the database. All of the actions in the app are triggered by keystrokes, pausing/resuming, quitting etc. and as well editing the text.

Now I want to read the text from `stdin` but the key-events are as sourced as well from stdin, but on a different thread. I came up with using a `stdin.lock()` - which works almost fine.

### The problem

How can I read a line from `stdin` in the main thread, without dropping the first letter, due to the event listener being triggered in its thread, before the lock in the main thread is acquired.

*expected behaviour:*

- press `t` => print `Reading from stdin!`
- type `abc<enter>` => print `You typed: Some("abc")`

*actual behaviour:*

- press `t` => print `Reading from stdin!`
- type `abc<enter>` => print `You typed: Some("bc")`

### Minimal non-working example

Here is an example that shows the described behaviour:

```
use failure;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use tui::backend::TermionBackend;
use tui::Terminal;

pub enum Event {
    Input(Key),
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub struct Events {
    rx: mpsc::Receiver<Event>,
    input_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Events {
    pub fn new() -> Events {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let input_handle = {
            let tx = tx.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let stdin = stdin();
                for evt in stdin.keys() {
                    match evt {
                        Ok(key) => {
                            if let Err(_) = tx.send(Event::Input(key)) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        Err(_) => {}
                    }
                }
            })
        };
        Events {
            rx,
            input_handle,
        }
    }

    pub fn next(&self) -> Result<Event, mpsc::RecvError> {
        self.rx.recv()
    }
}

pub fn key_handler(key: Key) -> bool {
    match key {
        Key::Char('t') => {
            println!("Reading from stdin!");
            let stdin = stdin();
            let mut handle = stdin.lock();
            let input = handle.read_line().unwrap();
            println!("You typed: {:?}", input);
        }
        _ =>{
            println!("no thing!");
        }
    };
    key == Key::Char('q')
}

fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    let stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode()?;
    let backend = TermionBackend::new(stdout);
    let mut terminal = Terminal::new(backend)?;
    terminal.clear()?;
    terminal.hide_cursor()?;
    let events = Events::new();
    loop {
        match events.next()? {
            Event::Input(key) => {
                if key_handler(key) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    terminal.clear()?;
    terminal.show_cursor()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

### Update

*Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name    = "mnwe"
version = "1.1.0"
edition = "2018"
autotests = false


[[bin]]
bench = false
path = "app/main.rs"
name = "mnwe"


[dependencies]
failure = "0.1"
termion = "1.5.3"
tui = "0.7"
```

Comment: when using external crate it's good to include Cargo config file that will give every information (most of the time version information) and a ready to use project.

Comment: What about modifying the code to not read from stdin in two different threads? Then `key_handler` will only handle keys that come on the channel. The other way to do it is to share a condition variable https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html between the two threads, but the flow of that would make only 1 thread run at a time.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I am stuck with exactly the same problem. I have an idea for a little bit clunky solution, but since you posted this question 2 years ago, I wonder whether you found a solution by now

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as correctly identified, is the race on `stdin().lock()` between `stdin.keys()` in the events thread and `stdin.lock()` in `key_handler` (which the events thread tends to win, and eat one key).

For the sake of the bounty, I see four possible approaches:

- At easiest, you can avoid having threads at all, and instead regularly poll for new input with [`termion::async_std`](https://docs.rs/crate/termion/1.5.6/source/examples/async.rs). (It's what I ended up doing for my own tui application. In the end, you're likely to be polling the event receiver anyway, so why not poll stdin directly.)
- If your problem allows it, you could do the stdin reading directly on the event thread. Instead of sending key events over the channel, you would send something you could call "user commands" over the channel:

```rust
// Channel data:
pub enum Command {
   StdinInput(String),
   Quit,
   // Add more commands
   Unknown(Key), 
}   
// Send side
thread::spawn(move || {
   for evt in stdin().keys() {
       match evt {
           Ok(key) => {
               let cmd = match key {
                   Key::Char('t') => {
                       println!("Reading from stdin!");
                       let input = stdin().lock().read_line().unwrap();
                       Command::StdinInput(input.unwrap_or(String::new()))
                   }
                   Key::Char('q') => Command::Quit,
                   _ => Command::Unknown(key),
               };
               if let Err(_) = tx.send(cmd) {
                   return;
               }
           }
           Err(_) => {}
       }
   }
})
// Receive side
loop {
   match events.next()? {
       Command::StdinInput(input) => println!("You typed: {}", input),
       Command::Quit => break,
       Command::Unknown(k) => println!("no thing: {:?}", k),
   }
}
```

- If you must absolutely have access stdin from to threads, I would not recommend using a `CondVar`, but passing the sender of another channel through the event channel. Why? Because it's much harder to get wrong. Any channel will do, but I think `oneshot::channel()` is most suitable here:

```rust
// Channel data
pub enum Event {
   Input(Key, oneshot::Sender<()>),
}
// Send side
for evt in stdin.keys() {
   let (shot_send, shot_recv) = oneshot::channel();
   match evt {
       Ok(key) => {
           if let Err(_) = tx.send(Event::Input(key, shot_send)) {
               return;
           }
           shot_recv.recv().ok();
       }
       Err(_) => {}
   }
}
// Receive side
loop {
   match events.next()? {
       Event::Input(key, done) => {
           match key {
               Key::Char('t') => {
                   println!("Reading from stdin!");
                   let stdin = stdin();
                   let mut handle = stdin.lock();
                   let input = handle.read_line().unwrap();
                   println!("You typed: {:?}", input);
                   // It doesn't really matter whether we send anything
                   // but using the channel here avoids mean surprises about when it gets dropped
                   done.send(()).ok();
               }
               Key::Char('q') => break,
               _ => println!("no thing!"),
           };
       }
   }
}
```

- You could also not do the `stdin().lock().read_line()` at all, but reassemble the user input line from the key stroke events. I wouldn't do that.